# Audio recorder not working recorder.js Flask, please any advice

Tags: javascript, python, flask, audio-recording

I have a web app that records voice with recorder.js and uploads it to the python-flask server.

The problem I am facing is that recorder is not working when running using flask server.

When I try to run HTML file directly it is working.

Following are my files:

My directory in windows:

```
├── file.wav(uploaded WAV file)
├── webapp.py
├── static
│   └── js
│       └── app.js
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

webapp.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = open('./file.wav', 'wb')
        f.write(request.files['audio_data'])
        f.close()
        if os.path.isfile('./file.wav'):
            print("./file.wav exists")

        return render_template("index.html", request="POST")   
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Recorder.js demo with record, stop and pause - addpipe.com</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Simple Recorder.js demo</h1>

    <div id="controls">
     <button id="recordButton">Record</button>
     <button id="pauseButton" disabled>Pause</button>
     <button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div id="formats">Format: start recording to see sample rate</div>
    <p><strong>Recordings:</strong></p>
    <ol id="recordingsList"></ol>
    <!-- inserting these scripts at the end to be able to use all the elements in the DOM -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type='text/javascript' src="static/js/app.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
//webkitURL is deprecated but nevertheless
URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var gumStream;                      //stream from getUserMedia()
var rec;                            //Recorder.js object
var input;                          //MediaStreamAudioSourceNode we'll be recording

// shim for AudioContext when it's not avb. 
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext //audio context to help us record

var recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton");
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton");

//add events to those 2 buttons
recordButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopRecording);
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pauseRecording);

function startRecording() {
    console.log("recordButton clicked");

    /*
        Simple constraints object, for more advanced audio features see
        https://addpipe.com/blog/audio-constraints-getusermedia/
    */

    var constraints = { audio: true, video:false }

    /*
        Disable the record button until we get a success or fail from getUserMedia() 
    */

    recordButton.disabled = true;
    stopButton.disabled = false;
    pauseButton.disabled = false

    /*
        We're using the standard promise based getUserMedia() 
        https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
    */

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        console.log("getUserMedia() success, stream created, initializing Recorder.js ...");

        /*
            create an audio context after getUserMedia is called
            sampleRate might change after getUserMedia is called, like it does on macOS when recording through AirPods
            the sampleRate defaults to the one set in your OS for your playback device

        */
        audioContext = new AudioContext();

        //update the format 
        document.getElementById("formats").innerHTML="Format: 1 channel pcm @ "+audioContext.sampleRate/1000+"kHz"

        /*  assign to gumStream for later use  */
        gumStream = stream;

        /* use the stream */
        input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        /* 
            Create the Recorder object and configure to record mono sound (1 channel)
            Recording 2 channels  will double the file size
        */
        rec = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1})

        //start the recording process
        rec.record()

        console.log("Recording started");

    }).catch(function(err) {
        //enable the record button if getUserMedia() fails
        recordButton.disabled = false;
        stopButton.disabled = true;
        pauseButton.disabled = true
    });
}

function pauseRecording(){
    console.log("pauseButton clicked rec.recording=",rec.recording );
    if (rec.recording){
        //pause
        rec.stop();
        pauseButton.innerHTML="Resume";
    }else{
        //resume
        rec.record()
        pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";

    }
}

function stopRecording() {
    console.log("stopButton clicked");

    //disable the stop button, enable the record too allow for new recordings
    stopButton.disabled = true;
    recordButton.disabled = false;
    pauseButton.disabled = true;

    //reset button just in case the recording is stopped while paused
    pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";

    //tell the recorder to stop the recording
    rec.stop();

    //stop microphone access
    gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();

    //create the wav blob and pass it on to createDownloadLink
    rec.exportWAV(createDownloadLink);
}

function createDownloadLink(blob) {

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    //name of .wav file to use during upload and download (without extendion)
    var filename = new Date().toISOString();

    //add controls to the <audio> element
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;

    //save to disk link
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename+".wav"; //download forces the browser to donwload the file using the  filename
    link.innerHTML = "Save to disk";

    //add the new audio element to li
    li.appendChild(au);

    //add the filename to the li
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filename+".wav "))

    //add the save to disk link to li
    li.appendChild(link);

    //upload link
    var upload = document.createElement('a');
    upload.href="#";
    upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
    upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
          var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload=function(e) {
              if(this.readyState === 4) {
                  console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
              }
          };
          var fd=new FormData();
          fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
          xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
          xhr.send(fd);
    })
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))//add a space in between
    li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li

    //add the li element to the ol
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
```

I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: The scope of this question is too wide, making it very hard to provide a good answer. You need to do some debugging, to see what part of the system is failing - is it the local JS code? The request sent to the server? The server's processing? What is working? This will make it possible for potential contributors to apply their expertise.

Comment: app.js is not loading as far as I can see, but I don't know why it is not loading

Comment: You should inspect the loaded page inside the browser, and see if the value of the `src` attribute of the `script` tag intended to load the script is what you would have expected it to be. Then, try loading this URL directly from the browser or a batch HTTP tool like `curl` and see what the result is.